# A robust method of tracking failed workers with ThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool, waithandle

I'm looking for a good method of tracking (counting) which workers have failed when queued with a Threadpool and using WaitHandle.WaitAll() for all threads to finish.

Is Interlocking a counter a good technique or is there a more robust strategy?

Comment: How do you envision the threads reporting their status? Would it be okay if they merely set a `bool` to `true` or `false`?

Comment: I was thinking the method queueing would have a static counter

Comment: I'm not following; it seems like a counter is only useful to tell you how many workers succeeded or failed but not which workers succeeded or failed. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry yes I only need a CPU t although which would be useful for a log

Comment: arghh iPhone auto correct, @Jason I want the count but also which failed would be good for logging

Comment: @Chris S: Ah, okay. So, the question remains: how do you want them to report state? I think the best solution is that they return a `bool` indicating success or failure. Is that acceptable to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's an approach that you could take. I've encapsulated the data that we want to track into a class `TrackedWorkers`. There is a constructor on this class that enables you to set how many workers will be working. Then, the workers are launched using `LaunchWorkers` which requires a delegate that eats an `object` and returns a `bool`. The `object` represents the input to the worker and the `bool` represents success or failure depending on `true` or `false` being the return value, respectively.

So basically what we do we have an array to track worker state. We launch the workers and set the status corresponding to that worker depending on the return value from the worker. When the worker returns, we set an `AutoResetEvent` and `WaitHandle.WaitAll` for all the `AutoResetEvents` to be set.

Note that there is an nested class to track the work (the delegate) the worker is supposed to do, the input to that work, and an `ID` used to set the status `AutoResetEvent` corresponding to that thread.

Note very carefully that once the work is done we are not holding a reference to the work delegate `func` nor to the `input`. This is important so that we don't accidentally prevent stuff from being garbage collected.

There are methods for getting the status of a particular worker, as well as all the indexes of the workers that succeeded and all the indexes of the workers that failed.

One last note: I do not consider this code production ready. It is merely a sketch of the approach that I would take. You need to take care to add testing, exception handling and other such details.

```
class TrackedWorkers {
    class WorkerState {
        public object Input { get; private set; }
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public Func<object, bool> Func { get; private set; }
        public WorkerState(Func<object, bool> func, object input, int id) {
            Func = func;
            Input = input;
            ID = id;
        }
    }

    AutoResetEvent[] events;
    bool[] statuses;
    bool _workComplete;
    int _number;

    public TrackedWorkers(int number) {
        if (number <= 0 || number > 64) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "number",
                "number must be positive and at most 64"
            );
        }
        this._number = number;
        events = new AutoResetEvent[number];
        statuses = new bool[number];
        _workComplete = false;
    }

    void Initialize() {
        _workComplete = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++) {
            events[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            statuses[i] = true;
        }
    }

    void DoWork(object state) {
        WorkerState ws = (WorkerState)state;
        statuses[ws.ID] = ws.Func(ws.Input);
        events[ws.ID].Set();
    }

    public void LaunchWorkers(Func<object, bool> func, object[] inputs) {
        Initialize();
        for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++) {
            WorkerState ws = new WorkerState(func, inputs[i], i);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.DoWork, ws);
        }
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);
        _workComplete = true;
    }

    void ThrowIfWorkIsNotDone() {
        if (!_workComplete) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("work not complete");
        }
    }

    public bool GetWorkerStatus(int i) {
        ThrowIfWorkIsNotDone();
        return statuses[i];
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> SuccessfulWorkers {
        get {
            return WorkersWhere(b => b);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> FailedWorkers {
        get {
            return WorkersWhere(b => !b);
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<int> WorkersWhere(Predicate<bool> predicate) {
        ThrowIfWorkIsNotDone();
        for (int i = 0; i < _number; i++) {
            if (predicate(statuses[i])) {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
class Program {
    static Random rg = new Random();
    static object lockObject = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int count = 64;
        Pair[] pairs = new Pair[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            pairs[i] = new Pair(i, 2 * i);
        }
        TrackedWorkers workers = new TrackedWorkers(count);
        workers.LaunchWorkers(SleepAndAdd, pairs.Cast<object>().ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Number successful: {0}",
            workers.SuccessfulWorkers.Count()
        );
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Number failed: {0}",
            workers.FailedWorkers.Count()
        );
    }
    static bool SleepAndAdd(object o) {
        Pair pair = (Pair)o;
        int timeout;
        double d;
        lock (lockObject) {
            timeout = rg.Next(1000);
            d = rg.NextDouble();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        bool success = d < 0.5;
        if (success) {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.First + pair.Second);
        }
        return (success);

    }
}
```

The above program is going to launch sixty-four threads. The `i`th thread has the task of adding the numbers `i` and `2 * i` and printing the result to the console. However, I have added a random amount of sleep (less than one second) to simulate busyness and I flip a coin to determine success or failure of the thread. Those that succeed print the sum they were tasked with and return `true`. Those that fail print nothing and return `false`.

Here I have used

```
struct Pair {
    public int First { get; private set; }
    public int Second { get; private set; }
    public Pair(int first, int second) : this() {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }
}
```

Comment: +5 for your effort. I think I may have worded the question badly or  I'd get more replies. One minor alteration is delegates rather than lambda

Comment: I'll rephrase that as lambda is fine. Are events a bad alternative? I understand the WorkItem limit, but is there a limit concerning the number of items you put in the threadpool? Sorry if I'm morphing this into 2 other questions

Comment: @Chris S: Well, the question was a bit unclear; you left a few things unspecified. It helps when asking questions to be as precise as possible, without being pedantic of course. That said, we cleared up a few things in the comments to your question. What do you mean by "are events a bad alternative"? As a signaling mechanism? As for the limit, there's a limit to the number of `AutoResetEvent` that can be waited on. If you need more threads, you'll have to do some work to split them among multiple collections of `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: Events as used to signal something happening back to the UI yes, and what happens when you queue say 10000 items into the ThreadPool, this must be 8000 object left on a Queue somewhere.

Comment: I probably won't use this exact solution but it's close enough